# Adding text labels to longitude and latitude points in shapefile map by plot()?

Tags: plotter

I have read my shapefile, and have also read my longitude-latitude points (in a csv file), that I want to overlay on the map. I have further created a character vector with the location names that I want to appear as labels on point on the map. I have tried to use the text function but the labels do not display.

Below is my code:

```
# Read shapefile
map1 <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="mymap")

# Read CSV file
cvsfile <- read.csv('./Hcenters.csv', sep=',', header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE)


# Convert CSV data frame to SpatialPoints class
coordinates(cvsfile) <- ~ lat + lon


# Make sure the two files share the same CRS
cvsfile@proj4string <- map1@proj4string


# Create label name text vector
names <- c("Bugono HC IV", "Namungalwe HC III", "Lubira HC III", "Busesa HV IV", "Busowobi HC III", "Baitambogwe HC III", "Mayuge HC III", "Kityerera HC IV", "Kigandalo HC IV")



# Plot shape file 
plot(map1, border="red", xlim=c(33.0, 33.7), lwd=2, axes=TRUE)

# Overlay longitude-latitude point locations to the map
points(cvsfile$lat ~ cvsfile$lon, bg="red", pch=15)

# Add label names to latitude-longitude points
text(cvsfile, labels = names, cex=0.7, pos=3)
```

However the labels do not display.

Where I am I going wrong?